# python: convert string into variable name

Tags: python

here is my python code:

```
>>> listName = 'abc'
>>> exec(listName+"=[]")
>>> print listName
>>> 'abc'
```

excepted output:

```
>>> print listName
>>> []
```

I want to define a new variable based on that string.

Comment: Alright so what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: when I am print listName it will return define string. but I want list.

Comment: @aevitas, I think the OP has shown what they tried.

Answer (score 2):

Even though that may be possible for global (and not local) variables, the better, cleaner, simpler, safer, saner (all in one word: pythonic) way is to use a dictionary for dynamic names:

```
values = {}
varname = get_dynamic_name()
# set
values[varname] = value
# get
values[varname]
```