# How to make a function with a function as a parameter

Tags: python, function

This is a function I've defined:

```
import sys

def hello():
    print("hello")

class parser():

    def parseSubcommand(self, name, function):
        if name == sys.argv[1]:
            result = function()
            return(result)


    def findArgument(self, name, function):
        print("dummy") #not started working on findArgument yet
```

But when I try to call it like this:

```
parser().parseSubcommand(name="hello", function="hello")
```

I'm getting the error

> function() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: can you paste the traceback of the error you are getting ?

Comment: function()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Then you are passing a string as the "function" argument. You need to post the rest of the code that shows how test is being called.

Comment: can you mention how are you calling test ?

Comment: sorry had problems editing post

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: convert string into variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028055/python-convert-string-into-variable-name)

Comment: you still cannot call a string,  use a dict mapping string name to function

Comment: i have no idea what you mean...

Comment: @Blaubeersirup, why are you using sys.argv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hello` is not the same as `"hello"`

`"hello"` is a string that can only be used as a string. It can't refer to variables unless used as a dictionary key to access a specific reference.

You want to use `hello` because that's the actual name of your function. Variable names are never accessed by string.

```
parser().parseSubcommand(name="hello", function=hello)
```

If you need to pass in the function names as a string, then you need to reference them in a dictionary, like this:

```
functionNames = {"hello":hello}
```

Comment: If the OP is using sys.argv to take args then this won't work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's true, I didn't pay attention to the `sys.argv` part. @Blaubeersirup You'll need to use a dictionary to use this properly with `sys.argv`

Comment: The op may not be using it at all it is hard to tell from the code, if they are taking arguments using optparse would probably be a better than trying to make their own parser

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
def function1():
    return 'hello world'

def function2(function_to_run):
    result = function_to_run()
    return result

function2(function1)
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer for other will have the solution in case encountered in your question.

Comment: We do not use mixedCase in Python for function names. PEP8 quote: *"Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability."*.

Comment: why would you not just `return function_to_run()`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I like to write explicit. but you can do `return functionToRun()` , it is the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the functions to the string representation of their names:

```
def hello():
    print("hello")

class parser():    
    funcs = {"hello": hello}
    def parseSubcommand(self, name):
         return self.funcs.get(name,lambda: print("Invalid name"))()



parser().parseSubcommand(name="hello")
parser().parseSubcommand(name="foo")
hello
Invalid name
```

Which if you are using `sys.argv[1]` you will need as you will always be getting strings.

If you want to take args using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/argparse.html#id1) for python3 or [optaprse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/optparse.html) for python2 might be a better idea.